# Configure ADFS for users who does not have Email Address

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, 2016, adfs

I have Successfully configured ADFS in my SharePoint 2016 On Premise Site.

The ADFS Authentication is working fine for users who have Email Addresses but in our organization, we have multiple users who **do not have Email** accounts, They **only have Active Directory** accounts.

I have configured ADFS by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/implement-saml-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-server) Blog.

As per this blog, The incoming Claims are EmailAddress & Role. but in my Case, the Users do not have Email addresses & I want to use their UserIDs only in my Custom Web Parts after Authentication.

I have also configured [LDAPCP](https://www.ldapcp.com/) to resolve People picker issues.

**The People Picker in my Site is not showing the users who does not have Email Addresses and I want to Grant access to those users as well who do not have Email Addresses.**

can someone Help me in this?